# how to detach a infinite sleep docker gracefully and why

Tags: docker, detach

1) I run following command to start a container:

```
docker run -d ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done;'
```

2) I attach to it using the following command.

```
docker attach xxxx
```

3) I cannot detach it using `ctrl +c` or `ctrl +p` `ctrl+q` sequence.

I wonder how to quit it and why `ctrl + c` doesn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The bash script is the main process in the container and it has `PID 1`. As explained in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#extended-description) the process with `PID 1` is treated differently than other processes:

> A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by
>   Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action.  So, the process
>   will not terminate on SIGINT or SIGTERM unless it is coded to do so.

It means that the script should trap the signals and do something with them. To make it quit declare a `trap`:

```
docker run -d ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'trap exit INT TERM; while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1; done;'
```

Keep in mind that bash will not handle any signals until the foreground process terminates (in this case `sleep`). Therefore there will be a delay depending on the sleep interval and the moment you press `CTRL+C`.
To exit immediately, `sleep` should be made interruptible (see [sleep, wait and Ctrl+C propagation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/478563/287790)):

```
docker run -d ubuntu /bin/bash -c 'trap exit INT TERM; while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1 & wait; done;'
```

The container is run  with the `-d` flag. You cannot detach unless you run it with `-it`.

> If the container was run with -i and -t, you can detach from a
>   container and leave it running using the CTRL-p CTRL-q key sequence

.